# Biochemistry for a mathematics student?

Tags: biochemistry

I am a second year mathematics student. I am mostly interested in statistics. Right now my curriculum doesn't offer me much choice (all second year courses are mandatory) but next semester I will be able to select the courses I want. Among the ones that are offered is a course called *Biochemistry*. It is actually a second year class for those how study chemistry and chemical engineering but I guess there must be applications of statistics in this field since it is also offered to third year math students.

My problem is that I am a math student: I have no knowledge or whatsoever in chemistry or biology. Granted that I had some in high school but back then I just learned everything by heart in order to pass.

My questions are the following:

- With no knowledge of chemistry, is it realistic to undertake a biochemistry class?
- The course description lists the following prerequisites: "Basic knowledge in general and organic chemistry". How important are these subjects in biochemistry? What are some good references (books) for self-learning these subjects?
- Is Stryer's Biochemistry a good book for self-learning?
- Are biochemistry and biostatistics related at all?
- Are there many applications of statistics in biochemistry?

I have already searched for some information on the internet but I'd like to have some specific answers.

If it helps here is the [information page](http://isa.epfl.ch/imoniteur_ISAP/!itffichecours.htm?ww_i_matiere=4144900&ww_x_anneeAcad=2013-2014&ww_i_section=944590&ww_i_niveau=6683117&ww_c_langue=en) of this class.

Finally I hope this kind of question is accepted here, if not please point me to a better place. Thanks in advance!

Comment: EPFL? Home of Michael Grätzel! Nice! Anyway, I can't give you a real advice, I'm "just an organic chemist". Does the faculty have a "Fachschaft" with students whom you could ask?

Comment: I will definitely try to find someone that took this class but I fear that there are not many math students that took it (it is optional after all).

Comment: Talk to the prof or to somebody who has taken it. I cannot imagine the value of memorizing amino acid structures, buffers' pH and capacity, or where the acetate carbon atoms are in cholesterol.  However, genomics is heavily statistical.  You can be of considerable value there.

Comment: It appears that you will need at least 2 semesters of O chem. I recommend Loudon for O chem. Take a look at it and if it makes sense to you, you should be ok.

Comment: It also looks like an intro class. I think that you may be ok without knowing all the o chem. However, you will have to put a significant amount of effort in filling in the gaps. It shouldnt be as bad as in mathematics but nevertheless be cautious.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you read up beforehand on pH and the related calculations and get a glimpse of physical chemistry (thermodynamics: reaction enthalpy, free energy, equilibria; kinetics: order of reactions, reaction speed, Michaelis-Menten kinetics) Maths behind that is easy, but you should be familiar with notations and useful as well as widely used approximations (I emphasize the widely used: as a maths student you may solve directly without approximation - but nevertheless approximations are employed in practice and if you don't know that it can be *very* confusing)

Comment: As chemist, I like the Stryer. As chemometrician I can tell you that there is a considerable need for statisticians in (bio)chemistry. Including but not limited to genomics.

Answer (score 3):

> With no knowledge of chemistry, is it realistic to undertake a biochemistry class?

I would say that taking a biochemistry course without *any* background in chemistry or biology would be very **difficult**, but it would be **possible**.

> The course description lists the following prerequisites: "Basic knowledge in general and organic chemistry". How important are these subjects in biochemistry?

The info page link that you gave would not work for me, so I can't tell how in-depth this course would be, but I know that the undergraduate biochemistry courses I have experience with expect you to be familiar with (at a minimum):

## Chemistry

- Bonding theory
- Molecular structure
- Nomenclature of organic molecules
- Polarity and its relation to hydrophobicity/hydrophilicity
- Basic organic reaction chemistry (particularly Lewis acid/base and functional group chemistry)
- Basic reaction kinetics
- Basic thermodynamics

## Biology

- Macromolecules (proteins, carbohydrates, fats)
- Cell structures
- Basic anatomy/physiology

All of these are fundamental to just about every concept in biochemistry, and they will probably expect you to already be familiar with if not good at them.

> What are some good references (books) for self-learning these subjects? Is Stryer's Biochemistry a good book for self-learning?

That I can't answer. I can tell you that [Voet & Voet's "Biochemistry"](http://amzn.com/0470570954) is a good biochem book, but I am not sure if it would be suitable for self-learning. I don't have experience with Stryer's book. Voet & Voet also have a ["Fundamentals of Biochemistry"](http://amzn.com/0470547847) book that might be better - but again, I don't have any experience with that one and can't compare to Stryer. In my personal experience, I have found that reading as many different books as possible is the best way to self-study, but your results may vary.

I can give you some suggestions for general chem and organic books:

## General Chemistry

- [Brown, Lemay, and Bursten's "Chemistry: The Central Science"](http://amzn.com/0321696727)
- [Tro's "Chemistry: A Molecular Approach"](http://amzn.com/0321809246)

These are both very easy to read and clearly explain all of the fundamental concepts, with lots of example problems worked out in detail.

## Organic Chemistry

- [Wade's "Organic Chemistry"](http://amzn.com/0321768418)

This is the only organic chem book I have much experience with, but I remember it being very easy to understand.

For biology textbooks, I'm afraid I can't be much help.

> Are biochemistry and biostatistics related at all?

Only in the sense that biostatistics is statistical methods applied to problems found in biology, and many problems found in biology are related to biochemistry. You would certainly want to learn some basic biochemistry if you were going to work on bioinformatics problems, for example.

> Are there many applications of statistics in biochemistry?

There are - particularly in areas like design of experiments, genomics, proteomics, and drug screening, and other various assays.